# Do I need to include system header file in the source if another header file already includes it?

Tags: c, header

For example, in the header file `example.h`, I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

And in the source file `example.c`, I wrote:

```
#include "example.h`
```

Do I still need to explicitly wrote these lines if I need functions of these libararies?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [**C preprocessor - Including files**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Including_files) ---
Sidenote: you can always use `ifndef` or `!ifdef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Keep in mind that includes works like some kind of text substitution, as it's done by the **preprocessor**.

When you write, on some file:

```
#include "someheader.h"
```

It's just like that line will be replaced with the actual content of the header file.

Comment: Note however that you should put a #include in the .c file rather than the .h file whenever possible, i.e. when there are no dependencies in the .h file for a given header.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't.

Include will, as it's named, include the whole content of your header file in your .c file.

If you are using linux, try `cpp example.c` or `gcc -E example.c` to see what `#include` does. *You will run the c-preprocessor on your file, which is the program that interpret all # started instructions before the copilation*